# Accessing external stylesheet in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

i have a unordered list(HTML) whose style i am changing conditionally in the code behind

```
<ul class="steps">
  <li class="" id="step1" runat="server">Step 1</li>
  <li class="step2" id="step2" runat="server">Step 2</li>
  <li class="step3" id="step3" runat="server">Step 3</li>
  <li class="step4" id="step4" runat="server">Step 4</li>
</ul>
```

in the code behind iam doing something

```
step1.Attributes["class"] = "step1";
step2.Attributes["class"] = "step2New";
```

something like this

If iam using internal styles then its working fine but when iam taking the same style sheet to external file then it is not working

Is it because i am assigning attributes using id i don't know please help me

the css file is some what like this

```
ul.steps li 
{
display:block;   
position:relative;
float: left;
color: white;
background: url('Images/steps.png') left -518px no-repeat;
min-height:60px;
height: 4em; 
min-width:202px;
width:20%;
line-height: 4em;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 130%;
margin-bottom:1em;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left:-20px;
}
ul.steps li.step1
{
    background-position: left -418px;
}
ul.steps li.step2,ul.steps li.step3New, ul.steps li.step4New,ul.steps li.step4New2
{
    background-position: left -118px;
}
ul.steps li.step2New
{
    background-position: left -218px;
}
ul.steps li.step2New2
{
    background-position: left -318px;
}
ul.steps li.step3, ul.steps li.step4
{
    background-position: left -18px;
}
/*ul.steps li.step3New
{
    background-position: left -118px;
}*/
ul.steps li.step3New2
{
    background-position: left -218px;
}
ul.steps li.step3New3
{
    background-position: left -318px;
}
/*ul.steps li.step4New
{
    background-position: left -118px;
}
ul.steps li.step4New2
{
    background-position: left -118px;
}*/
ul.steps li.step4New3
{
    background-position: left -218px;
}
li
{
list-style-type:none;
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
 background: url('../Images/steps.png') left -518px no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing the external CSS file correctly? You need to place a `link` element in the `head` section of the html, with the `href` attribute pointing to the CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="external.css" />
```

Comment: @Mac - then please post both the internal and external stylesheets, so we can see what is going on.

Comment: yes i have added the css file i am using the same as external as well internal

Comment: @Mac - since things are not working, I can only assume that you are not importing the external stylesheet correctly into your page.

Comment: may be Oded let me look into it once again and thanks a lot for your guidance

Comment: i got it its because of the background URL i am using 
background: url('Images/steps.png') left -518px no-repeat;
but i corrected it to
background: url('../Images/steps.png') left -518px no-repeat;